# Segurança com WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, segurança

Estou atualizando um site e estou com uma dúvidas relacionada a segurança do mesmo:

Nos arquivos de banco a variável de conexão com o banco é global;

A parte de PHP está junto com o HTML;

As variáveis das classes modelos são do tipo pública;

Não achei nenhuma proteção com expressão regular.

Não conheço muito o WordPress, ele possui um plug-in ou algo do gênero que "organize" o site ou o mesmo está desprotegido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é uma resposta absoluta para o que vc quer, mas como vc falou que é novo como o WP vou te dar umas dicas de segurança.

Primeiro mascare a pagina default de login do wordpress não deixe dessa forma:

```
https://www.seusite.com/wp-admin
```

**Plugin para trocar a URL padrão:** https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/ aqui tem um Guia que fala uma passo a passo desse plugin https://managewp.com/change-your-wordpress-login-url

Segundo remova ou renomeie a meta tag Generator não deixe dessa forma:

```
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress.com" />
```

**Plug in para remover o Generator** https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/meta-generator-and-version-info-remover/
Se quiser tirar na mão esse artigo pode te ajudar: https://tehnoblog.org/wordpress-security-how-to-hide-wordpress-meta-generator-version-info/

- Remova os arquivos de instalação do diretório!

Depois não permita que o usuário possa envias htmls, scripts ou qualquer coisa do gênero pelos campos de texto do seu site. Aqui vc pode ler como prevenir Spans nos comments: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Combating_Comment_Spam

Parece meio bobo, mas use o Recaptcha: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/

Algums Templates vem por defalt com alguns plug-ins de cadastro de usuários e algum usuário default que foi criado para publicar algum conteúdo padrão do template. Desabilite todos os plug-ins que não for usar. Desabilite também esse usuário padrão do tema.

*Verifique os tipos de arquivo que podem ser "upados" pelos usuários do site nos forms.*

**ROBOTS.TXT** aqui vai uma dica. Acredito que não seja do sei interesse deixar que motores de busca da China, Russia e outros além dos mais usados pelos brasileiros encontrem seu site. Então configure bem o Robots.txt e principalmente **não indexe as pastas do WordPress** Veja esse exemplo:

```html
User-agent: *
Disallow: /administrator/
Disallow: /administrator
Disallow: /components/
Disallow: /installation/
Disallow: /libraries/
Disallow: /logs/
Disallow: /modules/
Disallow: /plugins/
Disallow: /templates/

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: 
User-agent: googlebot-image
Disallow: 
User-agent: googlebot-mobile
Disallow: 
User-agent: MSNBot
Disallow: 

User-agent: Slurp
Disallow: /
User-agent: Teoma
Disallow: /
User-agent: Gigabot
Disallow: /
User-agent: Scrubby
Disallow: /
User-agent: Robozilla
Disallow: /
User-agent: Nutch
Disallow: /
User-agent: baiduspider
Disallow: /
User-agent: naverbot
Disallow: /
User-agent: yeti
Disallow: /

Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Sitemap: http://www.seusite.com.br/site
```

**Se possível use a versão mais nova do PHP**!

Dois artigos em portugues com outras dicas.

https://www.canalwp.com/guia-do-iniciante/boas-praticas-para-garantir-wordpress-security/

https://blog.apiki.com/2017/02/22/13-passos-seguranca-do-wordpress/

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas, pode colocar na resposta como fazer o primeiro e o segundo

Comment: São plugins agora estou na correria mas assim que der te respondo com calma

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam coloquei os plugins e uma dica sobre o Robots.txt